pass method to Composable as parameter inside clickable lambda. The expression is unused
I have the following Composable
@Composable
fun ClickableBar(text: String, action: () -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(40.dp)
            .background(color = AppPrimaryGreen)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { action },
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(text = text)

        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_right),
            contentDescription = "",
        )
    }
}

I want to perform action method when that Row is tapped but action gets highlighted and it says The expression is unused.
What I'm doing wrong??

There are actually two ways you can do this.
dev.tejasb proposed the following to invoke the action function by adding parentheses:
.clickable { action() }

But you can also do this:
.clickable(onClick = action)

Both options provide a value for the onClick parameter. While the first option creates a new lambda and calls action in it, the second option directly passes action as the parameter. Note that onClick has the type () -> Unit, the same type as action so you can simply assign the parameter as seen in option 2.

You need to call it like this:
action()

Since action is a lambda function passed to ClickableBar function, you need to include parentheses when invoking it, just like with any other function call.

It was this! Awesome. Thank you very much
